# DataGridView Columns not generating from Custom DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I have written a class that implements the `IBindingListView` interface, `BindableList<T> : IBindingListView`.

```
_abilityList = new BindableList<Ability>();
dataGridViewAbility.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dataGridViewAbility.DataSource = _abilityList;
```

For some reason the `DataGridView` does not Generate Columns, so when I add data to my `BindableList<T>` the `DataGridView` throws an error stating i need to add columns first.

What makes this weird is that if I add an Object to my `BindableList<T>` then the columns are generated just find. I also switched out My class for `BindingList<T>`, add nothing to it and the columns generate just fine.

I am at a loss as to why the `DataGridView` will not Generate the Columns from my Generic Binding List when it is empty. The Framework knows what the type of the generic is when the program builds.

UPDATE:

Ability Class

```
class Ability
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public Int32 Generation { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Effect { get; set; }
}
```

I do not see why people are having trouble understanding this but i have made a new Winform App that still has the same problem.

```
private BindableList<Ability> _abilityList;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _abilityList = new BindableList<Ability>();

        Button b = new Button();
        b.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        b.Click += new EventHandler(buttonGetData_Click);
        this.Controls.Add(b);

        DataGridView _grid = new DataGridView();
        _grid.Location = new Point(100, 0);
        _grid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        _grid.DataSource = _abilityList;
        this.Controls.Add(_grid);
    }

    private void buttonGetData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _abilityList.Add(new Ability());
    }
```

OnListChanged Event

```
protected virtual void OnListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ListChanged != null)
    {
        ListChanged(this, e);
    }
}
```

When the line `_abilityList.Add` runs, this fires the `ListChanged(this, e);`. This runs and the DataGridView throws and Error, No Columns added to View. If I add and Object to the `BindableList<T>` first before Assigning it as the `DataSource` the Columns will Generate.

Comment: You can share some code to take more chance to receive useful answers:)

Answer (score 4):

Simply assigning the `DataGridView.DataSource` property does not generate the columns right away. In my experience, if you need the `DataGridViewColumns` right away, then there are 4 critical lines of code to force the columns to be created:

```
        DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
        BindingList<Ability> list = new BindingList<Ability>();
        dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dgv.DataSource = list;

        int colCount = dgv.Columns.Count; // 0
        //--------
        // force columns to be created
        using (var g = dgv.CreateGraphics()) {}
        using (var f = new Form()) {
            f.Controls.Add(dgv);
            f.Controls.Remove(dgv);
        }
        //--------
        int colCount2 = dgv.Columns.Count; // 4
```

**Edit:** Alternative approach which is much faster, especially when properties on the `DataGridViewColumns` (e.g. `AutoSizeMode` and `SortMode`) need to be set.

```
public static void Refresh(DataGridView view, DataTable table) {
    bool origAuto = view.AutoGenerateColumns;
    view.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    view.DataSource = table;
    view.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
    view.AutoGenerateColumns = origAuto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the Answer but this is not the case. The DGV was added to Controls by the Designer. Also the process of the file is done through a Button click so the DGV shows up on the UI before I process.

Comment: @OlinCausey I tested the above code (without the force create lines) and the DGV appeared with columns. So you should create a small complete example the reproduces your problem. Possibly you have some other code running that is hiding all of the columns (e.g. `col.Visible = false;`).

Comment: Add the section `// force columns to be created` did nothing for my GDV which was declared in and displayed on its parent form. The Columns and Rows collections were still empty, despite a bound data source with content.

Comment: @Zarepheth A separate approach to try (ignoring all the above code) is to first assign `dgv.DataSource = ...`, then set `dgv.BindingContext = new BindingContext();`

Comment: Also, make sure `dgv.AutoGenerateColumns` is true.